# huge performance drop with increment by one

Tags: java, performance

I'm working on a blobscanner, at the moment i have around 130 frames a second. I have a vector array called cornerPoints. If i use:  `cornerPoints[i].x = x;` then my frameRate is above 100. If i use:

```
cornerPoints[i].x = x+1;
```

or:

```
cornerPoints[i].x = x;
cornerPoints[i].x ++;
```

Then my frameRate drops with around 100 frames. How can it have such a big impact?
And what can be done about it.

```
protected void indexesToXY(int width, int height) {

       int x;

       for (int i = 0; i < nOfCornerIndexes; i++) {
           x = cornerIndexes[i] % width;

           // if i use x + 1 the frame rate drops with about 100 frames
           cornerPoints[i].x = x;
           cornerPoints[i].y = (cornerIndexes[i] - x) / width;
       }
       nOfCornerPoints = nOfCornerIndexes;

   }
```

Comment: I think this question is unanswerable without an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I doubt that you lose 30 fps by incrementing a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
       x = cornerIndexes[i] % width + 1;

       cornerPoints[i].x = x;
```

However, I think the performance drop is not from the cost of addition. Probably value of cornerPoints have some other effect in other parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's rather impossible. The addition is much cheaper than other operations like modulus and division and array access.

What's possible is that the changed data has some impact in a different piece of code. That's why an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) is needed (as stated in a comment).

Looking at the generated assembly (not bytecode!) could tell us more. With an SSCCE there are chances that someone gets interested in it and will spend quite some time on the analysis (without an SSCCE there's no hope).